# War file automated deployment

Tags: java, war

So I deploy war files on a Linux box using java automatically

and the same commands are always used

```
ps -ef | grep java
kill - 9 (java process)
java -jar ROOT.war &>/dev/null &
```

However, I get different versions for it so like

```
ROOT_1.0.2.war
ROOT_1.0.3.war
ROOT_1.0.4.war
ROOT_1.0.5.war
```

I want the script to see the new .war and deploy it automatically 
and keep it deployed which is why I use  `&>/dev/null &` so it runs in the till it is killed again till the new version is put in that directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo Enter the name of the process you want to kill eg ROOT.war?
enter code here
read process

##Kill selected process 
file="$process"
 if [ -f "$file" ];
then
   pkill -9 -f $process
   echo process stopped >> satrixWar.txt
 sleep 3s

## Start Up selected process 
echo Enter the name of the process you want to start
read process2
java -jar $process2 &>/dev/null &
echo process starting up>> satrixWar.txt

else
   echo "Process $process does not exist" >&2
fi

##Confirm new proess is up
echo What is currently installed >> satrixWar.txt 
ps -ef | grep $process2 >> satrixWar.txt

mail -a text file path -s "name" 
"email.com" < /dev/null

rm -rf War.txt
```